# Complex SQL Code

Tags: sql

I am having trouble with a SQL query that corresponds to multiple different tables.  I have written the following code, but it seems to combine every single booking with every invoice rather than finding the specific invoice that matches a specific booking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT INVOICE.invoice_id, 
           g.guest_first_name,
           g.guest_last_name, 
           g.booking_num_guests,
           g.booking_num_nights,
           CURRENCY.currency_name,
           INVOICE.invoice_nightly_rate,     
           INVOICE.invoice_deposit_amount,
           INVOICE.invoice_paid,
           ACCOUNT.account_name 
        FROM INVOICE    
        INNER JOIN BOOKING
             ON INVOICE.invoice_booking_id = BOOKING.booking_id
        INNER JOIN CURRENCY
             ON INVOICE.invoice_currency_id = CURRENCY.currency_id
        INNER JOIN ACCOUNT
             ON INVOICE.invoice_account_id = ACCOUNT.account_id
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT GUEST.guest_first_name, 
                  GUEST.guest_last_name,
                  BOOKING.booking_num_guests,
                  BOOKING.booking_num_nights
           FROM BOOKING
           INNER JOIN GUEST
               ON BOOKING.booking_guest_id = GUEST.guest_id) g
               ON INVOICE.invoice_booking_id = BOOKING.booking_id";
```

Comment: What's the last inner join for? You already joined `INVOICE` and `BOOKING` in the first inner join.

Comment: The Booking table contains the guest id and i thought i needed the last inner join to get the guest details.

Comment: Why don't you just join `GUEST` and `BOOKING` using `ON BOOKING.booking_guest_id = GUEST.guest_id` without `SELECT GUEST.guest_first_name, GUEST.guest_last_name, BOOKING.booking_num_guests, BOOKING.booking_num_nights FROM BOOKING`?

Comment: For future reference: SQL-related questions should include sample data and the output you're trying to obtain from that data, and should include a tag for the specific SQL DBMS you're using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, or whatever), as dialects and functionality differ between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already joined `INVOICE` and `BOOKING` table in the first inner join, the last inner join should be between `BOOKING` and `GUEST` table. Change your query to below

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            INVOICE.invoice_id, 
            GUEST.guest_first_name, 
            GUEST.guest_last_name, 
            BOOKING.booking_num_guests, 
            BOOKING.booking_num_nights, 
            CURRENCY.currency_name, 
            INVOICE.invoice_nightly_rate, 
            INVOICE.invoice_deposit_amount, 
            INVOICE.invoice_paid, 
            ACCOUNT.account_name 
        FROM INVOICE    
        INNER JOIN BOOKING 
            ON INVOICE.invoice_booking_id = BOOKING.booking_id
        INNER JOIN CURRENCY 
            ON INVOICE.invoice_currency_id = CURRENCY.currency_id
        INNER JOIN ACCOUNT 
            ON INVOICE.invoice_account_id = ACCOUNT.account_id
        INNER JOIN GUEST 
            ON BOOKING.booking_guest_id = GUEST.guest_id";
```